# Plane Diagrams in topology (quotient maps)

Tags: general-topology

Through plane diagrams show that
there exist quotient maps

p1 : D^2 → S^2 and 
p2 : [0, 1] × [0, 1] → S^2

I require to find a precise geometric description of the above to maps, however, I am not too sure of how to begin. Please guide

Thank you

Comment: How does a disk look if you collapse all of its boundary to a single point?

Comment: A Sphere or Ellipsoid?